# Universal header and footer

Tags: html, header, footer

I created a website for my mom a while back and I finally want to make it cleaner and make a universal header and footer so that I only have to change the one document when I update it instead of every page. I spent a while looking around, but I was unable to make anything work. I have a good understanding of HTML and CSS, but I'm pretty much a novice and haven't really used javascript, if thats what this entails, so detailed help would be really appreciated! How do I go about this? (If it matters, the website is hosted on DreamHost).
Here is the basic HTML code I have for the header and footer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<header>
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="(logo)">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <footer>
    <p> Email: email@gmail.com </p>
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need server-side scripting (php, asp, jsp etc) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like react or a framework like angular 2 or vue js to extend the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to do this. You would simply `include header.php` for example. It is possible to use any other server-side code.

It is also possible with JavaScript, but keep in mind that JavaScript is executed on the Client side, so that some users could experience issues due to deaktivated javascript inside the browser.